# how to put carousel scroll arrow key to middle of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap carousel scroll arrows key in left and right side. but currently it is on the top side of the banner page. but I need put it middle of the page. My css class is this for arrow keys.

```
.carousel-control.left {margin-left: -85px; color: black;}
.carousel-control.right {margin-right: -85px; color: black;}
```

how can put my arrow keys to middle of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this.

```
.carousel-control {
position: absolute;
top: 50%; 
z-index: 5;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Sample

http://jsfiddle.net/WmMXa/671/

Comment: may i should remove both .carousel-control.left {margin-left: -85px; color: black;}
.carousel-control.right {margin-right: -85px; color: black;}

Comment: @John it would be easier to see with a working fiddle. i created a sample.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="display:table;height: 100vh;width: 100%;">
  <div style="display: table-cell;padding: 0;height: 100vh;vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
  <p style="background:red;display:inline-block;padding:50px"> Content </p>
  </div>
</div>
```